# Building an entirely installation-free Windows standalone via Matlab Compiler

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I'm encountering a serious problem while trying to deploy a Matlab program as a stand-alone for Windows.

My end users are employees in some corporation and have only access to static computers. While they can *download, unpack and execute* stuff, they don't have *installation* privileges, so they're unable to install the Matlab Compiler Runtime (MCR). Unfortunately, they need MCR in order to run my deployed/compiled Matlab program. The `deploytool` offers me the option to "*include MCR in the package*", but it doesn't really do that. Instead, it packages the MCR *installer*, which is useless in my case as described above.

So how can I create a stand-alone application that runs on Windows **out of the box**, even without MCR installed and without installing it first? There has to be a way to compile this all the way down to binary...

Comment: As @thewaywewalk mentioned, you can't deploy a MATLAB program to an end-user without the end user installing the MCR first. If the end-user doesn't have admin privileges to do so, then IT will have to do it for him/her.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't run Matlab code standalone without having **MATLAB** or the **MATLAB Compiler Runtime** installed. But it is legal to distribute the MCR to the customers to make them able to use your programs.

Alternatively you can use the **MATLAB Coder** to convert your code to C/C++, which is not completely issue-free, as just a [subset of the Matlab language](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/description2.html) is supported.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126407/matlab-compiler-vs-matlab-coder) for the differences between [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.de/products/matlab-coder/) and [MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.de/products/compiler/).

Answer (score 4):

Just ask IT to install the MCR, that only needs to happen once. After that the users should be able to execute your programs.

Note: There is a reason that the MCR needs to be installed, and can't just be executed. Therefore I don't expect there to be a 'trick' to avoid this.