# ActiveX control of Word. Select text and images

Tags: vba, matlab, ms-word, activex, office-interop

This is what I have done so far:

```
word = actxserver('Word.Application');

document = word.documents.Open('C:\Documents and Settings\kz7213\Desktop\Test.docx');

selection = word.Selection;

selection.TypeText('Big Finale'); 
selection.Style='Heading 1'; 
selection.TypeParagraph;

FIG1 = figure('Visible','off'); plot([1 2 3 4 5],[4 1 3 5 7]);

print -dmeta

selection.Paste; 

selection.Style='Heading 1';

selection.InsertCaption('Figure','Test figure 1'); %Not working
selection.Style='CaptionStyle';

selection.TypeParagraph;
```

How can I select previous entered text such as "Big Finale" to edit it, or select the figure I pasted with the selection. Paste command in order to make a caption for the image?

Comment: in which moment you want to select 'Big Finale'?  after you typed it or after you run complete of your code? I've changed the tags for your question to more appropriate.

Comment: I want to select it after I have run my complete code!

Comment: I could give you some solution in word-vba, will you convert it on your own to 'matlab-office-interop' code?

Comment: That would be nice! Thank you!

Comment: perhaps you use: `document.InlineShapes.Item(1)` to get the inserted image? Here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7617438/97160) where I used this. @KazJaw: I could help with the translation if you want..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution in VBA for MS Word:

```
'to find a text
    Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="Big Finale", Wrap:=wdWrapAlways

'to select inline shape
    ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Select
```

Alternative solution to find a inlineshape(s) is to use `.Find.Execute method` with the following settings:

```
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="/", Wrap:=wdWrapAlways, MatchWildcards:=True
```

Comment: in MATLAB that would be: `selection.Find.Execute('Big Finale',[],[],[],[],[],[],1)` for the first one (where `1` is the underlying value of the enum `wdWrapAlways` for `Wrap` option). Note that we had to specify empty values for the other optional arguments of [`Find.Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.execute.aspx), since MATLAB only supports positional arguments

Comment: Second one is: `document.InlineShapes.Item(1).Select` while the last one: `selection.Find.Execute('/',[],[],true,[],[],[],1)`

Comment: small correction: `Wrap` should be one of [`WdFindWrap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdfindwrap.aspx) constants, which is `wdFindContinue` in this case (also represented by `1`)