# Matlab and Word: How to update a text in Word using Matlab

Tags: matlab, ms-word, cross-reference

I have the following question. Imagine there is a MS-Word document in which a given data set is described. For instance, it may be written: "The data set at hand contains a time series of stock prices from the year 2010 to 2015".

The exact time series (here stock prices), as well as the specific start and end dates (here 2010 and 2015) may change depending on which data set I'm considering. Now imagine you have three strings in Matlab, e.g.

string1 = 'stock prices'

string2 = '2010'

string3 = '2015'

Ideally I would like the Matlab and Word documents to be interlinked in such a way that the text in Word will change when I manipulate one of the strings. So, for instance, if I set string1 to 'commodity prices', then Word should show: "The data set at hand contains a time series of *commodity* prices from the year 2010 to 2015".

I have unfortunately no clue how this could be fixed. In Word, it is possible to use a Cross-Reference, but this would all stay within Word.

I would be happy for any suggestions.

Comment: If you're open to using LaTeX to create a PDF file, this becomes very simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveX control of Word. Select text and images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101841/activex-control-of-word-select-text-and-images)