# Appending to an excel in matlab

Tags: matlab, append, export-to-excel

I am following up on [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821380/insert-an-image-into-a-excel-cell-in-matlab/45849046#45849046). By using:

```
excelWorkbook.SaveAs('figtest.xlsx');
```

I am overwriting the existing excel. I have created a function which uses the code to save two images to excel. Now I want to iterate over a number of images, process each image and then save the result alongside the original image to an excel. Obviously calling the function each iteration is a bad idea since, each iteration is deleting the results of former iterations.

How can I add the current data to the excel file without deleting any former data?

Is there a better way to do this?

Note that the data is images and not simple numeric data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a COM server once, iterate over the images and place them in the desired cells, quit the server and then delete the server object.

Building from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45849046/5698672), here is a working example with 5 of many built-in images:

```
%Some sample images
im{1}=imread('peppers.png');
im{2}=imread('cameraman.tif');
im{3}=imread('pears.png');
im{4}=imread('greens.jpg');
im{5}=imread('bag.png');

excel = actxserver('Excel.Application'); % Create server object
excelWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(1);  % Add a workbook
excelSheet = excel.ActiveSheet;          % Get the active sheet

f = figure('visible','off');             % To not show the images in MATLAB
dpi = get(groot, 'ScreenPixelsPerInch'); % Get screen dpi
for k=1:5
    imshow(im{k});
    print(gcf, sprintf('-r%d', dpi), ...     % Print the figure at the screen resolution
        '-clipboard', '-dbitmap');           %    to the clipboard as a bitmap
    %Adjust the cell names where you want to paste the images as desired
    excelSheet.Range(['B',num2str(k)]).PasteSpecial();
    %Unlocking aspect ratio to adjust height and width of the image according to the cell
    excelSheet.Shapes.Item(k).LockAspectRatio='msoFalse';
    excelSheet.Shapes.Item(k).Width=excelSheet.Range(['B',num2str(k)]).Width;
    excelSheet.Shapes.Item(k).Height=excelSheet.Range(['B',num2str(k)]).Height;     
end
excelWorkbook.SaveAs('figtest.xlsx');     % Save workbook to a file
excelWorkbook.Close();                    % Close workbook
excel.Quit();                             % Quit server
excel.delete();                           % Delete server object
```

which gives:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to place each set of images in its own sheet, creating new sheets in the Excel file as needed. Here's some sample code, modified from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45824172/52738):

```
% Start COM server:
excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
excelWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(1);
excelWorksheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;

% Initializations:
dpi = get(groot, 'ScreenPixelsPerInch');

for iSheet = 1:nIterations  % Based on how many image sets you process

  % Get a blank sheet:
  if (iSheet == 1)
    excelSheet = excel.ActiveSheet;
  else
    excelSheet = excelWorksheets.Add([], excel.ActiveSheet, 1);
  end

  % Load, process, and plot your images here:
  ...

  % Paste image into sheet and adjust cell size:
  print(hFigure, sprintf('-r%d', dpi), '-clipboard', '-dbitmap');
  excelSheet.Range('B2').PasteSpecial();
  excelSheet.Range('B2').RowHeight = excelSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Height;
  widthScale = excelSheet.Range('B2').ColumnWidth./...
               excelSheet.Range('B2').Width;
  excelSheet.Range('B2').ColumnWidth = excelSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Width.*widthScale;

end

% Save and close workbook and stop COM server:
excelWorkbook.SaveAs('figtest.xlsx');
excelWorkbook.Close();
excel.Quit();
excel.delete();
```

Comment: Is there a limitation on the cell sizes? I am getting Dispatch Exception for `excelSheet.Range('B2').RowHeight = excelSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Height;`. I have tried `excelSheet.Range('B2').RowHeight = 409` and got no error,I have received the same error upon`excelSheet.Range('B2').RowHeight = 410`

Comment: @havakok: Yes, as mentioned [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3), cells are limited to a maximum width of 255 characters and a maximum height of 409 points.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this [here](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/74537-adding-data-into-existing-excel-sheet-from-matlab):

```
xlApp = actxserver('Excel.Application');
xlApp.visible = 1;
%Open the the spreadsheet
xlworkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('figtest.xlsx');
xlsheet = xlworkbook.ActiveSheet;
mydata=randn(1,3);
data=xlsread('figtest.xlsx');
%Determine last row
last=size(data,1);
newRange=last+1;
xlCurrRange = xlsheet.Range(['A', num2str(newRange),':C', num2str(newRange)]);
xlCurrRange.Value2 = mydata;
%Save and Close the Excel File
invoke(xlworkbook,'Save');
invoke(excelApp,'Quit');
delete(excelApp);
```

Also, you may want to try [this script](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28600-xlsappend) from the File Exchange.

Comment: This will work for simple numeric data. I am not sure this will work for images. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Adding data to an excel file is not well defined: creating new sheets or adding data to an existing one?

Therefore, you probably need the following methodology:

1. Open the existing excel file (to which you want to add data)
2. Add the new data to the opened excel file
3. Save this edited excel file