# Any function in matlab to write the output of matlab code to excel file each time the code gets executed without over writing the data

Tags: excel, matlab

Output of my matlab code gives out a string each time it is executed. I need to save the string in a excel sheet each time without overwriting the previous data in the excel sheet. The new string must be added in a new cell in the excel sheet.

Comment: You need use 'writematrix' or 'writecell' Matlab functions: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/exporting-to-excel-spreadsheets.html

Answer (score 1):

The `writecell` function has an optional `range` parameter, which allows you to write a certain range, without touching the rest of the sheet.

```
writecell({'A' 'B' 'C'},'C.xls','Range','A1:C1')
```

In case you want to write numeric data instead of strings, `writematrix` is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

The example:

```
filename = 'testdata.xlsx';
for i = 1:10
textdata = {['some text ', num2str(i)]};
writecell(textdata,filename,'Sheet',1,'Range',['B',num2str(i)]);
end
```

[image]

Comment: in this code all the 10 output strings are generated at a time. i need to save the strings after each time my code is executed.

Comment: In this code each string is generated iteratively. Just insert your code instead 'textdata = {['some text ', num2str(i)]}'

Answer (score 1):

Daniels approach works with `writecell`, `writetable`, and `writematrix`, you just need to keep track of the range (or update the row indices of your range...)

There is a more complicated (or sophisticated) approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955681/appending-to-an-excel-in-matlab#45961662) or [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/178989-open-edit-and-save-excel-file-with-matlab).

The question is if you

1. really need to write there to the excel file consistently, or if your RAM allows to store everything in a matlab-table and write it once at the end to a file
2. does it have to be an excel file, or is a .mat-file OK? (Which is easier to update)
3. if you want to write to a comma-separated file, can you write to a .csv file? You can append a string (that can be a formatted line) to a text file, see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/28667-how-to-append-data-or-values-to-an-existing-csv-file).

Option 3 is probably all you need if you don't want to change your original code.

```
dlmwrite('test.csv',MATRIX,'delimiter',',','-append');
```