# Export multiple MATLAB plots to Excel?

Tags: excel, matlab, plot, export

I have the following MATLAB code:

```
for i=1:3
    a=rand(5,1);
    b=rand(5,1);
    plot(a,b);
    xlabel('X Values');
    ylabel('Y Values');

    xlswritefig(gcf, 'Results.xlsx', 'Sheet1', 'D2') 
    % from https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24424-xlswritefig

end
```

This generates just the 3rd plot in an Excel file. However, I want to generate all 3 plots, side-by-side, in a single Excel file. How can I do this?

EDIT:

I modified the code to use `actxserver` instead of `xlswritefig`. However, as the code runs, it generates 3 excel pop-ups showing the plots. However, the file `results1.xlsx` contains no plots. I don't even want `peaks` in the code, but if I exclude it, nothing even shows up in the Excel pop-ups. Here's the new code:

```
cellPos = {'D2', 'J2', 'P2'};

for i=1:3
    a=rand(5,1);
    b=rand(5,1);
    plot(a,b);
    xlabel('X Values');
    ylabel('Y Values');

    f1 = figure; peaks;

    % Connect to Excel, make it visible and add a worksheet
    xl = actxserver('Excel.Application'); set(xl,'Visible',1);
    xl.Workbooks.Add(1); xls = xl.ActiveSheet;

    % Paste in the MATLAB figures
    print(f1, '-dbitmap'); xls.Range(cellPos{i}).PasteSpecial;
    xls.Shapes.Item(1).PictureFormat.CropLeft  = 30;
    xls.Shapes.Item(1).PictureFormat.CropRight  = 30;
    xls.Shapes.Item(1).Height  = 100;
    xls.Shapes.Item(1).Left = xls.Range(cellPos{i}).Left;
    excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');  % Create server object
    excelWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(1);   % Add a workbook
    excelWorkbook.SaveAs('results1.xlsx');  % Save workbook to a file
    excelWorkbook.Close();                 % Close workbook
    excel.Quit();                          % Quit server
    excel.delete();                        % Delete server object     


end
```

Comment: You're writing all the figures to the same cell `D2`. Write them to different cells

Comment: That worked. However, now all the plots are a default size. How can I resize them so that they are a size specified by the user? I provided an updated code in the original question

Comment: @aaa: The [`xlswritefig`](https://github.com/michellehirsch/xlswritefig/blob/master/xlswritefig.m) function uses [`hgexport`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgexport.html) to copy the figure to the clipboard. That seems to be limiting your control of the figure size. The answers I linked to below use [`print`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html), which gives you more options. You may want to use the code from those answers instead of `xlswritefig`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing all the images to the same sheet and cell `'D2'`. You need to change the cell on each loop iteration so each figure is in a different place instead of one on top of the other. For example, this places a figure in every third cell horizontally:

```
cellPos = {'D2', 'G2', 'J2'};
for i = 1:3
  ...
  xlswritefig(gcf, 'Results.xlsx', 'Sheet1', cellPos{i});
end
```

You may also want to have a look at the answers to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45821380/52738), which detail how to create an image from a figure and insert that image into an Excel cell, resizing the image or cell as needed.

### Edit:

Based on your edit (where you are now using some code from the link I gave above) you have quite a few errors. You only need to start the [COM server](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/actxserver.html) once *before* your loop, and then close it *after* your loop. You also need to create your figure window `f1` *before* you plot your data. Here's a rewrite using the [example code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45824172/52738) (with cell modifications omitted):

```
cellPos = {'D2', 'J2', 'P2'};             % Cells to place figures in
dpi = get(groot, 'ScreenPixelsPerInch');  % Get screen dpi
excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');  % Create server object
excelWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(1);   % Add a workbook
excelSheet = excel.ActiveSheet;           % Get the active sheet
for i = 1:3
    a = rand(5, 1);
    b = rand(5, 1);
    f1 = figure;
    plot(a, b);
    xlabel('X Values');
    ylabel('Y Values');
    print(f1, sprintf('-r%d', dpi), ...  % Print the figure at the screen resolution
          '-clipboard', '-dbitmap');     %   to the clipboard as a bitmap
    excelSheet.Range(cellPos{i}).PasteSpecial();  % Paste from clipboard
    % Modifications to cell size, etc.
end
excelWorkbook.SaveAs('Results.xlsx');  % Save workbook to a file
excelWorkbook.Close();                 % Close workbook
excel.Quit();                          % Quit server
excel.delete();                        % Delete server object
```

Comment: I looked at the code from that link. I updated the code I now use in my original post and the errors I'm getting

Comment: that updated code works better, but `results1.xlsx` still contains no plots in it